# Update the Vue3 reactive object by passing it in props

Tags: javascript, vue.js

#### code sample

https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-dew-rwuvh?file=/src/components/ChildComponent.vue

I made the object reactive.
Pass it to the child component as props.
When I set it to v-model and try to update it, a warning is displayed on the ESLint.

- It seems that no error is displayed on the console at runtime.

```
Unexpected mutation of "person" prop. (Vue / no-mutating-props) eslint
```

It works, but I don't think the error should be ignored.

Want to know how to update a reactive object with a child component?

Comment: FWIW, rule docs contain everything you need to know about the problem.

Comment: https://github.com/vuejs/eslint-plugin-vue/issues/1371